# Modifying an instance variable is also modifying the original array

Tags: ruby, arrays, instance-variables

I am working through a simple exercise creating a Pez dispenser class in Ruby. Here's a snippet:

```
class PezDispenser

    def initialize(flavors)
        @flavors = flavors
    end

    def get_pez
        @flavors.shift
    end

end
```

When I create a new dispenser with an array of flavors and then call #get_pez:

```
flavors = ["cherry", "grape"]
example = PezDispenser.new(flavors)
example.get_pez
```

The original flavors array is modified along with the @flavors instance variable:

```
p flavors #=> ["grape"]
```

I've found that I can prevent this by initializing:

```
@flavors = Array.new(flavors)
```

But I still don't understand why @flavors would be tied to the original array otherwise. Any help or explanation would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your initialize method to

```
def initialize(flavors)
    @flavors = flavors.clone
end
```

Otherwise you're tracking the original flavors, which was passed by reference.

By putting the `clone` operation into `initialize`, you isolate the `@flavors` state from the outside.  You won't get surprised by the behavior if somebody modifies the original `flavors` array outside your class, you won't be modifying the original `flavors` via operations on your cloned copy, and you won't be counting on users to remember to manually do the clone.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this seems like a safe solution.